# How to share a variable from the client side to the server side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-handlebars

I need a random generation of questions in one .js file, later I check the *input checkbox* by *id* and output the result at the end. And for the quick displaying questions, I use .handlebars. I need to make a quiz. (modules - express, express-handlebars)

*Just in case **server.js***

```
const express = require("express"),
  app = express(),
  exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
const routes = require("./routes/index");
app.listen(3000);
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.engine(
  "handlebars",
  exphbs({
    defaultLayout: "main",
  })
);
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");
app.use("/", routes);
```

I have a **data.json** file with questions (there are actually more than 1000)

```
(data = [
  {
    "ids": "1",
    "question": "how?",
    "answers": [
      "1assd",
      "2asdsa",
      "3sadas",
      "4asdas",
      "5asdsad"
    ],
    "correct": [1, 2, 3, 4]
  },
  {
    "ids": "2",
    "question": "where?",
    "answers": [
      "1sadas",
      "2sdadsaf",
      "3sadsa"
    ],
    "correct": [1, 2, 3]
  },
]
```

I open it in my **public/js/app.js** and randomize the questions

```
var mydata = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
let questi = []; // <------- to index.js ?
for (let i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
  questi[i] = mydata[Math.floor(Math.random() * mydata.length)];
}
console.log(questi);
```

But don't know how **questi** send to **routes/index.js**

```
const express = require("express"),
  fs = require("fs"),
  router = express.Router();
router.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.render("test", {
    style: "main",
    quests: questi, // <------------- from app.js ?
  });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Is it possible to do this somehow differently, so that my **views/test.handlebars** can easily take values?

```
{{#each quests}}
<div id={{ids}}>
    <ul>
        <h3>{{question}}</h3>
        {{#each answers }}
        <li><input type="checkbox" id={{../ids}}_{{@key}} value="{{@key}}">{{.}}</li>
        {{/each}}
        <hr>
    </ul>
</div>
{{/each}}
<p>answered:</p>
```

*And just in case **views/layouts/main.handlebars***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>{{title}}</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/{{style}}.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  {{{body}}}
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="data.json"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I make a link for .json and with `fetch` take values